# How to prove the map is continuous?(Stein's complex analysis Chapter3 exercise 16)

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing the disc $|z|\leq 1$. Suppose that $f$ has a simple zero at $z=0$ and vanishes nowhere else in $|z|\leq 1$. Let $$f_{\epsilon}(z)=f(z)+\epsilon g(z).$$Show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then

(a) $f_{\epsilon}(z)$ has a unique zero in $|z|\leq 1,$ and

(b) if $z_{\epsilon}$ is this zero, the mapping $\epsilon\to z_{\epsilon}$ is continuous.

---

I have been asked to solve the question as homework.

Part (a) is actually trivial by applying Rouche's Theorem since $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic and we have $$|f(z)|>\epsilon|g(z)|$$ when $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. But Part (b) is difficult for me. As the exercise show, the zero $z_{\epsilon}$ is a function of variable $\epsilon$, and I don't know how to determine where is the zero $z_{\epsilon}$. I can never show $$\lim_{h\to0}(z_{\epsilon+h}-z_{\epsilon})=0$$without knowing the exact expression of $z_{\epsilon}$.

So I decide to consider the inverse map: $z_{\epsilon}\to\epsilon$. And I get $$\epsilon=-\frac
{f(z_{\epsilon})}{g(z_{\epsilon})}.$$ This is a continuous function. Can I end proof by saying "Since the inverse function is continuous"? Or my consideration is actually wrong? HELP! Please show me the correct proof or the right way solving the exercise.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility of doing a Google search before posting this question?

Comment: yes，but I did it in a wrong way.hahah